# Unable to get constraints of NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

This is my code:

```
let b = NSLayoutConstraint(item: some, attribute: fromAttribute, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: some2, attribute: toAttribute, multiplier: multiplier, constant: -5)
b.isActive = true
self.layoutIfNeeded()
print(b.constant)
print(some.constraints.first(where: {$0.constant == -5 }))
```

And this is my print:

```
-5.0
nil
```

How can I get that constraint back in code? Why does it print out nil? I want to animate the constraint's constant later on. Thanks.

Comment: Make it a class-level variable / property, instead of a local-scoped variable.

Comment: @DonMag Would it make a difference you think? You mean variable B class-level variable right?

Comment: How do you now that the constraint is added to `some`? Show us the view hierarchy please. If `some2` is not a subview of `some`, then this cannot work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the core question:

**How can I get that constraint back in code?**

Ideally, you don't. You save it to a variable when you create it, e.g.:

```
var myConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

func x() {
   let b = NSLayoutConstraint(...)
   ...
   myConstraint = b
}
```

**Why does it print out nil?**

When setting `isActive = true`, the constraint is added to the closest common superview. For example, if `A` is a superview of `B` and you have a same-width constraint, then the constraint is added to `A` and it won't be present on `B`.

The constraint will be added to `some` only if `some2` is a subview of `some`.

Comment: Yes I was just reading your comment and I thought maybe it is added to my superview (some2). Well, that was another hour scratching my head  >:(

Answer (score 0):

Use a class-level variable to hold the constraint you want to modify. If you are using storyboards / Interface Builder, you can also assign a constraint as an IBOutlet.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var constraintToAnimate: NSLayoutConstraint?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        constraintToAnimate = NSLayoutConstraint(item: some, attribute: fromAttribute, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: some2, attribute: toAttribute, multiplier: multiplier, constant: -5)
        constraintToAnimate.isActive = true

    }

    // later, perhaps in a button tap...

    func animateIt() {

        constraintToAnimate?.constant = 100

    }

}
```